# Magento REDSYS SHA256 issue error 180 on TPV and no order confirmation

Tags: magento, sha256

We have a commerce in Magento version 1.8.1 and using Redsys module to implement payment trough VISA.
With the new implementation of SHA256 for SSL, Redsys provides the following module to upgrade/install Redsys module (actually version 2.8.3):

http://www.redsys.es/wps/wcm/connect/redsys/52db13b8-af9e-4d1c-b796-3890b72ddb75/redsys_magento_V2.8.3.zip?MOD=AJPERES

Installation went alright: placed things where it should be and started debugging.

So, here we go: All runs, it appears to work perfectly on first try BUT orders are still in "New" state and not in "Processing". Also TPV platform, in Notifications, tells a "180" which means it returns to my commerce but something goes wrong.

Obviously something is going bad in the return it the code is the genuine code of the module.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, the codification of Order Id as sent to Redsys in line **79**:

In  **\app\code\local\Excellenceredsys\Redsys\controllers\IndexController.php**

$numpedido =  str_pad($orderId, 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

so the result is: 0001XXXXXXXXXX (at least for my commerce)

That's generating a problem in line **301**:

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orde);

It isn't able to get order by id because of the padding zeros.

- **Quick Solution**: $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orde*1);
- **No Var Type Change Solution**: take off the padding zeros, maybe with a substr function.

Answer (score 1):

Use new Magento module community support http://redsys-magento.devopensource.com/
this is compatible SHA256

Comment: Yeah, well, sorry for not using yours

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  The orders were OK but they stay in pending status and I didn't receive the email with the order but I received the email from redsys with the transaction.

I changed line 301 and the status is processing and I receive the email with the order from the customer.